# Подсчитать кол-во символов в тексте

Tags: c++, массивы, символы

Нужно подсчитать именно сколько букв и символов
a-125
n-18
b-60
также пробел и цифры.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

 //для windows не подсчитывается символ '\r', только '\n'
bool load_info(const char* filename, size_t& lines, size_t& cnt) {
    std::ifstream fp(filename);
    if (!fp.is_open())
        return false;

    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> i(fp), e;
    size_t n = 0, m = 0;
    for (; i != e; ++i, ++m) {
        if (*i == '\n')
            ++n;
    }
    fp.close();

    lines = (m > 0) ? n + 1 : n;
    cnt = m;
    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    char fn[] = "c:\\project\\1.txt";

    size_t lines, cnt;
    if (load_info(fn, lines, cnt)) {
        std::cout << "lines: " << lines << std::endl
            << "count: " << cnt << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <locale>

using std::cout;

bool load_info(const std::string& filename, std::vector<std::uint_least64_t>& stat)
{
    stat.clear();
    stat.resize(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() + 1UL, 0);

    std::ifstream fin(filename, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    if (!fin.is_open())
        return false;

    auto fin_begin = fin.tellg();
    fin.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    auto fin_end = fin.tellg();
    auto fin_size = fin_end - fin_begin;
    fin.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    for (decltype(fin_size) pos = 0; pos < fin_size; ++pos)
    {
        char symb = 0;
        fin.read(&symb, sizeof(symb));
        if (!fin.good())
            return false;
        ++stat[static_cast<unsigned char>(symb)];
    }

    return true;
}
    
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::uint_least64_t> stat;
    std::locale loc("");

    if (load_info("c:\\project\\1.txt", stat))
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < stat.size(); ++i)
            if (stat[i] > 0)
            {
                if (std::isprint((unsigned char)i, loc))
                    cout << "symb = '" << (unsigned char)i << "' ";
                else
                    cout << "symb = ''  ";
                cout << "code = " << i << " stat = " << stat[i] << "\n";
            }

    return 0;
}
```